# Cronjob not working at autoscaled instance's creation

Tags: linux, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, cron

We're trying to work with AWS EC2 auto scaling groups. We created an instance, set up like we need with ubuntu 16.04 and all the software we need, then made an image from that instance. We then created a launch configuration and auto scaling group from it. All is fine at that point and we see the instances being created.

The problem is that we have some cronjobs that need to work at reboot and every 5 minutes but they do not work until we ssh in into the newly created instance at least once. Everything else is working fine, tomcat is running and the cronjobs starts working if we ssh into it, but we want this to be automated. Note that we just need to ssh into the instance for the cronjobs to start working, we don't even need to enter crontab -e.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Check the system logs.

Comment: could you paste the crontab here?

Comment: Here is the cronjob that really need to be working and is not, until we ssh in. `*/5 * * * * sudo /usr/local/bin/checkportal.sh` I checked the permissions on this script, everything is in order and what this script does is just check if our website return 404, then restart tomcat.

Comment: Maybe you should look into why Tomcat fails. Alternately you can skip this health check and have it done by the auto scaling group - if it reports unhealthy it'll be removed from the group and replaced.

Comment: Actually Tomcat is working fine but it's just the root app that is failing to start on new instances, everything else works fine. I guess I'll try to dig deeper why the root app is not starting.

Comment: I suggest you pay the $30 for a month of AWS developer support. They should be able to help you solve this problem reasonably quickly, their support is meant to be excellent.

Comment: You might want to check to see if there are any requirements of the script that might not apply before first login.  For example, the first login via ssh might create a home directory.  You could also try moving the cronjob to one of the cron folders (/etc/cron.d), and drop the sudo requirement.

Comment: Can't comment, have to post an answer.<br>
Not an Unbutu guy. I use RedHat/CentOS. Noticed something in your crontab. <br>
<code>*/5 * * * * sudo /usr/local/bin/checkportal.sh</code>
<br>
What user is this? You have sudo in the crontab. Do you have the NOPASSWD option set in your sudoers file? <br>
It may be that you need to log in to set the password so that sudo will work the first time. After that, because you are running every 5 minutes, your timeout for the sudo password will never expire. <br>
<br>
_Why not just put this in the root/admin crontab?_